# How to configure 6 network cards in Debian 7

Tags: linux-networking, debian-wheezy

I am new in Debian and I have machine with 6 (six) network cards. It's gona be a cheap router, but Linux makes ethX devices only for 4 network cards (eth0...eth3):

```
root@dc-02:~# dmesg | grep eth
[    1.474080] 8139too 0000:00:0c.0: eth0: RealTek RTL8139 at 0xd400, 00:50:ba:ca:90:87, IRQ 19
[    1.475862] 8139too 0000:00:13.0: eth1: RealTek RTL8139 at 0x7800, 00:c0:df:12:05:1f, IRQ 18
[    1.477545] eth2: 100/10M Ethernet PCI Adapter at 0001d000, 00:02:44:45:01:84, IRQ 16.
[    1.479051] eth3: 100/10M Ethernet PCI Adapter at 0001b800, 00:02:44:47:04:b0, IRQ 17.
[   15.225247] 8139too 0000:00:0c.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
```

lspci shows all cards:

```
root@dc-02:~# lspci
 . . .
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
00:0b.0 Ethernet controller: Device 0000:f640 (rev 10)
00:0c.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc RTL8139 Ethernet (rev 10)
00:0d.0 Ethernet controller: MYSON Technology Inc SURECOM EP-320X-S 100/10M Ethernet PCI Adapter
00:0e.0 Ethernet controller: MYSON Technology Inc SURECOM EP-320X-S 100/10M Ethernet PCI Adapter
 . . .
```

So, how can I turn on eth4 and eth5? Is it possible?
Thanks a lot and best regards.

Comment: Looks like you're only loading the 8139too driver and not whatever driver runs `SURECOM EP-320X-S` cards.  Not sure what the driver would be though.

Comment: yeah, quite apparently there is no driver loaded for SURECOM, therefore udev did not create additional interfaces for it.

Comment: Thanks all. I'll check it. We found some cards with RTL8139 on board.

Comment: I count five network cards in that `lspci` output.

Comment: @Michael Hampton: probably I cut one of them. There was 6. But now (with other cards) - only five.

Comment: So, rtl8139 works fine! I have all five cards working. Thanks!

Comment: Self-answer your question with what you had to do to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

So, when I replaced `SURECOM` NIC by `RTL8139` based chipset NIC's everything was fine.

The problem realy was in the drivers. Great thanks for advices to DerfK and Danila Ladner.

Only one problem was in that moment - to give "right" IP for each NIC.

I have searched in google for renaming `ethX` devices in udev and found, that I can write riles for naming devices by udev. In Debian 7 this rules already exists in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. I I have edited this file for my requirements.

```
root@dc-02:/etc/udev/rules.d# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules                                                                                                                                                                     
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.                                                                                                                                                                             
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single                                                                                                                                                                               
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.                                                                                                                                                                                          

# PCI device 0x1186:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0 (8139too)                                                                                                                                                                           
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:ba:ca:90:87", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"                                                                                        

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0 (8139too)                                                                                                                                                                           
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:22:88:86:78", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"                                                                                        

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0a.0 (8139too)                                                                                                                                                                           
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:22:39:47:4f", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"                                                                                        

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0 (8139too)                                                                                                                                                                           
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:22:39:47:64", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth3"

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0 (8139too)                                                                                                                                                                           
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:40:f4:87:f6:e4", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth4"                                                                                        

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0a.0 (8139too)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="4c:00:10:a1:e9:9c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth5"
```

So, now - there is no any problems and everything works fine. I think, this question is closed.